# Atraçao de objetos em python

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame

Estou escrevendo um código onde uma imagem vai em direção a outra só que por alguma razão não esta funcionando.

Eu pego a distancia entre elas cálculo a força de gravitacional `Fg = G*M1*M2/D^2` de atração entre elas e decomponho o vetor resultante em `x` e `y` assim incrementando o `x` e o `y` a cada 0.1 segundo o o valor dividido por 10.
Acredito que meu erro deve estar nos cálculos em relação ao tipo de variável long, int e float. Porém Não consigo resolver.

Código:

```
# -*- coding: cp1252 -*-
from __future__ import division
from pygame import *
from random import *
from math import *

class ob():
    def __init__(self,x,y,m,caminho = "x.png"):
        self.vx = 0
        self.vy = 0
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.m = m
        self.img = image.load(caminho)

def main():
    init()
    screen = display.set_mode((800, 400))
    display.set_caption('Basic Pygame program')
    background = Surface(screen.get_size())
    background = background.convert()
    background.fill((250, 250, 250))
    MOVEEVENT, t = USEREVENT+1, 10
    time.set_timer(MOVEEVENT, t)

    c = time.Clock()
    screen.blit(background, (0, 0))
    display.flip()

    G = 6.67384*(pow(10,-11))

    ob1 = ob(50,50,4)
    ob2 = ob(100,100,4)    


    while 1:
        dx = ob2.x - ob1.x
        dy = ob2.y - ob1.x 
        dt = pow(pow(dx,2)+pow(dy,2),1/2)
        background.fill((250,250,250))
        background.blit(ob1.img,(ob1.x,ob1.y))
        background.blit(ob2.img,(ob2.x,ob2.y))

        F = (G*ob1.m*ob2.m)/(pow(dt,2))
        for y in event.get():
            if y.type == QUIT:
                display.quit()
            if y.type == MOVEEVENT:
                if ob1.x <100 and ob1.y < 100:
                    ob1.vx = F*0.01
                    ob2.vy = F*0.01
                    ob1.x = ob1.x +ob1.vx*0.01+((F*pow(0.01,2))/2)
                    ob1.y = ob1.y +ob1.vy*0.01+((F*pow(0.01,2))/2)
                    print ob1.vx,ob1.vy , ob1.x,ob1.y
        c.tick(100)
        screen.blit(background,(0,0))
        display.flip()



if __name__ == "__main__": main()
```

minha linha de raciocinio e que a posiçao deles sera dada pela formula S=S0+V0*T+A*T^2/2
suas velocidades serao calculadas em Vx= F*0.1 e Vy = F*0.1 onde F e  F=G*M1*M2/Dt^2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Em primeiro lugar, você está calculando o valor absoluto da força entre os dois objetos (i.e. compondo a distância a partir das posições `x` e `y`), mas não está **decompondo** essa força novamente em coordenadas usando o seno e o cosseno. Além do resultado sair errado - e idêntico pras direções `x` e `y` - ele sempre será positivo, independentemente das posições relativas entre os dois objetos.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
F = (G*ob1.m*ob2.m)/(pow(dt,2)) if dt else 0

Fx = F * (ob2.x - ob1.x) / dt if dt else 0
Fy = F * (ob2.y - ob1.y) / dt if dt else 0

...
```

Em segundo lugar, você está usando a força entre os objetos como aceleração. Faltou aplicar a fórmula `F = m * a`:

```
if ob1.x <100 and ob1.y < 100:

    ax = Fx / ob1.m
    ay = Fy / ob1.m
```

Em terceiro lugar, a fórmula da posição que você citou está correta, mas sua implementação não - você está atualizando a velocidade **antes** da posição, de modo que é `Vf` que está sendo utilizada no cálculo, e não `V0`:

```
    ob1.x = ob1.x +ob1.vx*0.01+((ax*pow(0.01,2))/2)
    ob1.y = ob1.y +ob1.vy*0.01+((ay*pow(0.01,2))/2)
```

Por fim, `a*0.01` é o delta v; você precisa somá-lo à velocidade inicial, em vez de substituí-la:

```
    ob1.vx += ax*0.01
    ob2.vy += ay*0.01
```

Comment: Eu Nao lembrava muito sobre decomposição de vetores muito tempo se ver, mas deu pra entender perfeitamente explicou bem muito obrigado. @mgibsonbr